# Разделение Numpy-массива на части при помощи np.array_split

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Обрабатываю массив arr, который является изображением, преобразованным в numpy массив. Он трёхмерен, первые два вложенных элемента - строки\столбцы, 3 - пиксели в строках\столбцах. Я пытаюсь разделить его при помощи np.array-split(), я создал такой код:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.array_split(arr,16)
print(f)
for i in f:
    f[i]= np.array_split(f[i],16)
```

Однако получаю следующую ошибку:

*TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index*

Comment: Что должно получиться в результате?

Comment: я делю массив на чанки заданного размера массив, а следовательно и изображение

Comment: Что вы делаете, я вижу. Что вы хотите получить - нет. Что должно быть в результате? Опишите результат, не процесс.

Comment: i - это элемент массива, а не индекс. поэтому должно быть не `f[i]= np.array_split(f[i],16)`, а что-то вроде `res= np.array_split(i,16)`.